# How to modulate from A to B using sin(a) and distance in P5 js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am calculating each's box distance from the centre of the coordinate system using dist().

I am trying to use all of the above but am unable to get it right.

I am stuck and trying to do this for a few days, please do help.

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);
  
  background(220);
  
  camera(-200, -200, -200,   // camera position (x, y, z)
         0   , -100,    0,   // camera target (look at position) (x, y, z)
         0   ,    1,    0);  // camera up axis: Y axis here

  for (let x=0; x < width; x +=20){
    for (let z=0; z < height; z +=20){
      push();
      // ground plane is XZ, not XY (front plane)
       normalMaterial();
             stroke(0);
       strokeWeight(1);
      translate(x, 0, z);  
         let distance = dist(0, 0, x, z);
         let length = (((sin(frameCount) + 1)/2) * 100);
         //box(20);     
         box(50, length);
         pop(); 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the box depends on the distance of the center to the box. e.g.:

```js
let distance = dist(width/2, height/2, x, z);
let length = (((sin(TWO_PI * distance/600 + frameCount * 0.01) + 1)/2) * 100);
```

The speed can be changed by changing (*0.01*) and the wavelength can be changed by changing (*600*).

The width and height of the [`box`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/box) must be 20:

```js
box(20, max(0.01, length), 20);
```

You must put the code in the [`draw`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) function:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);
  
  camera(-200, -200, -200,   // camera position (x, y, z)
         0   , -100,    0,   // camera target (look at position) (x, y, z)
         0   ,    1,    0);  // camera up axis: Y axis here
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (let x=0; x < width; x +=20){
    for (let z=0; z < height; z +=20){
        push();
        // ground plane is XZ, not XY (front plane)
        normalMaterial();
        stroke(0);
        strokeWeight(1);
        translate(x, 0, z);  
        let distance = dist(width/2, height/2, x, z);
        let length = (((sin(TWO_PI * distance/600 + frameCount * 0.01) + 1)/2) * 100);   
        box(20, max(0.01, length), 20);
        pop(); 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```